# Why do I have to add extra tokens before the 'using' statement?

Tags: c++, compilation, token

## Functions.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "definitions.h"
#include "globals.h"

};using namespace std;
```

This is in `functions.h` Now we have `main.cpp` that includes the header

## Main.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Other stuff
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason I have to write `};` before the `using` statement. It won't let me compile unless that is before it.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Perhaps definitions.h or globals.h are missing a `};`?  what happens if you remove includes, one-by-one?  Does it compile with no headers included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is probably caused by a missing `};` in the `globals.h` file.

The preprocessor literally pastes the contents of the `#include`d header files into your source file. So if there is a syntax error in one of the header files, there will be a syntax error in the source file that includes it.

And I know this doesn't fix your problem, but you should never use `using namespace std;` in a header file, as that pollutes the global namespace for every translation unit that includes that header. It's much better to keep `using namespace` statements local to a single source file, or better yet, just type out `std::`.

Comment: You were right that was the case. I had to chop a lot off a very large struct and completely missed it.